# Why retain property may not retain on Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, properties, retain

Why the following code crashes? Commented code doesn't crash.

```
@property (retain) NSDate *lastCurrentDate;

...

@synthesize lastCurrentDate;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    BOOL crash = [lastCurrentDate isEqualToDate:[NSDate date]]);
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //lastCurrentDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
    lastCurrentDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

So, why retain property may not retain on Objective-C?

Comment: can you report the crash error?

Comment: I have just tried the same thing at my end but it doesn't crash. Is there any thing missing in the code shown here. I would appreciate if you update if anything is missing.

Else the better you can update with the crash error.

Comment: I suppose it crashes because the variable is null when you send the message isEqualToDate since it was initialized yet; is an error to initialize a variable in the method viewDidDisappear

Comment: Harry, it doesn't crash because of strange Apple's politics: the application should work on developer's device and should crash on user's device. But only if you are not using `NSZombie = YES` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `@synthesize lastCurrentDate` - you also create variable named '`lastCurrentState`', and when you write `lastCurrentDate = [NSDate date];` you directly access this variable. Properties should be accessed via dot: `self.lastCurrentDate = ....;`

In last xCodes you don't need to write synthesize - it do it automatically, but creates variable named with '_' prefix. It equals to: `@synthesize variable = _variable;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.lastCurrentDate = [NSDate date]`. Because when you use `self.lastCurrentDate`, it will assign via `setter` method. You declare vaiable via retain property, So your setter method will do two operation,`assign` and `retain`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you assigned directly to the instance variable, instead of using the
property accessor method:

```
self.lastCurrentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Why instance variable has name "lastCurrentDate" instead "_lastCurrentDate"?

Comment: @Altaveron: Because you have `@synthesize lastCurrentDate;` in your code, see other answer.